How to move SwiftUI Bottom Tab to the top?
The following SwiftUI code will generate Bottom Tab
public struct TeamBContentView : View {
    public init() {}
    public var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TabView {
                Text("This is home screen")
                    .tabItem {
                        Text("Home")
                        Image(systemName: "house.fill")
                    }
                Text("This is about us screen")
                    .tabItem {
                        Text("About Us")
                        Image(systemName: "person.fill")
                    }
                Text("This is contct us screen")
                    .tabItem {
                        Text("Contact Us")
                        Image(systemName: "phone.fill")
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}

As below

If I want to have it at the Top, is there a way easily transfer it to the Tab to the top of the screen instead?

You will need to write your own tab bar. The system tab bar will be on the top if this is on an iPad though.

I don't think you can re-locate the native tab bar from the bottom to the top of the screen. But what you can do is hide the native tab bar by applying .toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar) to each child view of the TabView. Then you can show your own custom tab bar, which can be located wherever you like. See this answer for an example implementation of a custom tab bar.

public struct TeamBContentView : View {
@State private var selectedTab = 0
public init() {}

public var body: some View {
    VStack {
        // Use picker view and set picker style as segmented
        Picker("Tabs", selection: $selectedTab) {
            Text("Home").tag(0)
            Text("About Us").tag(1)
            Text("Contact Us").tag(2)
        }
        .pickerStyle(.segmented)
        .padding()
        
        Spacer()
        
        // Then display the view based on the tab selected
        switch selectedTab {
        case 0:
            Text("This is home screen")
        case 1:
            Text("This is about us screen")
        case 2:
            Text("This is contact[enter image description here][1] us screen")
        default:
            Text("This is home screen")
        }
        Spacer()
    }
    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden() // use this to hide the back button
}
}


Nice one!! Thanks. Upvote yours instead of mine answer, given yours is Vanila style and no animation glitch too.

One simple way is to use the library provided by
https://github.com/QuynhNguyen/SlidingTabView
As of how to add the Package of the library, refers to the last section of this article
Then you can use the below code,
import SlidingTabView

public struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var tabIndex = 0
    public init() {}
    public var body: some View {
        VStack {
            SlidingTabView(selection: $tabIndex, tabs:["Home", "Friends", "Settings"], animation: .easeInOut)
            Spacer()
            if tabIndex == 0 {
                Text("Home")
            } else if tabIndex == 1 {
                Text("Friends")
            } else if tabIndex == 2 {
                Text("Settings")
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}



